# Ubuntu FTP user has access to every directory

Tags: ubuntu, chroot, vsftpd

I just created a new user on Ubuntu Server 16.04.3 LTS with `useradd`. I have vsftpd installed, and `#chroot_local_user=YES` still commented out. Yet when i connect with my user through FTP to my server, he can see and access every single folder on the entire server (so not just his home folder).

Did i do something wrong?

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Please show full config.

Answer (score 1):

You have `chroot_local_user = YES` commented out and it defaults to `NO`. As the [`vsftp.conf` documentation](https://security.appspot.com/vsftpd/vsftpd_conf.html) says, your desired state requires this to be set `YES`.

> ```
> chroot_local_user
> ```
>
> If set to `YES`, local users will be (by default) placed in a chroot()
>   jail in their home directory after login.
>
> Warning: This option has security implications, especially if the
>   users have upload permission, or shell access. Only enable if you know
>   what you are doing. Note that these security implications are not
>   vsftpd specific. They apply to all FTP daemons which offer to put
>   local users in chroot() jails.
>
> Default: `NO`